# Codeigniter session set_flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble using set_flashdata in CI.

Controller:

```
if($var == true) {
        // some action here
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('fail', 'Error');

        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['fail'])): ?>
<p class="text-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['fail'] ?></p>
```

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
<p class="text-success"><?php echo $_SESSION['success'] ?></p>
```

I don't see any message, no matter what.
Tried with `var_dump($this->session->flashdata('success'));`

How can I solve this issue?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure that you have everything initialized correctly (`$this->load->library('session');`) and that you have your encryption key set in the config file.

Secondly, Codeigniter does not utilize PHP's native `$_SESSION`, they implement their own. So you should not test if it is set with `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['fail'])): ?>`

I would try something like :

```
<?php if(isset($this->session->flashdata('fail'))): ?>
<p class="text-danger"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('fail'); ?></p>
```

Comment: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` as you can see it is set in autoload, I tried your suggestion and I still don't see anything on the page.

Comment: I just tested in a view with: `$var = TRUE;

if($var == true) {
        // some action here
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('fail', 'Error');
    }
    
    ?>
<p class="text-danger"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></p> ` and it worked. It gave me an alert of success. It must be in your configuration. And I will ask again, are you sure your encryption key is set? You can edit your question with your configuration if you want us to take a look.

Comment: I have encryption key and it is not working. What do you want me to add in my question? Thanks.